# How to configure TinyMCE 6 to insert a <br> by pressing only Enter (rather than Shift+Enter)?

Tags: tinymce

How can I configure TinyMCE 6 to insert a <br> by pressing only Enter (rather than Shift+Enter)?

For example, when I run the following, I cannot create a new line simply by clicking [Enter].  Pressing [Enter] does nothing.  Is there a setting that allows me to click [Enter] rather than having to know about [Shift+Enter]?

```
<p contenteditable="true" id="myeditor">
  Line1
  <br>
  Line2
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "#myeditor",
    inline: true,
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough"
});
</script>
```

Live example: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/zciaab/2

Comment: You could remove the inline=true and post process the HTML to convert the p->br, /p->null

Comment: (And in terms of user experience you could make the paragraphs inserted look like line breaks by tweaking the margin/padding?)

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, the “inline” mode is central to our UX, so we cannot remove that.  But in that mode with <p>, [enter] does nothing, so we can’t act on the second suggestion either.

Answer (score 0):

One method to fix this implementation could be to configure the editor.addShortcut API to add a `<br>` element whenever the enter keydown event happens.

I believe the syntax is to use `(mceSetAttribute, true, '<br>')` method ([docs are here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/TinyMCE3x@Command_identifiers/#instancecommands)) with the addShortcut method.

I've updated the fiddle to show how it could work:https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Kciaab/4

EDIT: it is the `execCommand('InsertLineBreak')` core command method not `setAttribute`. [Docs Link for core commands](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/editor-command-identifiers/#miscellaneous-core-commands).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RobinJoe... unfortunately, the fiddle update didn't work (seemed to be a couple of syntax issues that caused the TinyMCE to not appear). I wonder if you might have time to fix it up?  I'm interested in whether that suggestion will work or not.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @andysd, I checked my syntax and I think I have fixed the bracer (`)}`) errors: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Kciaab/3 It seems to be working with a different keydown – I configured `ctrl+n` – but I could not get the `Enter` keypress to work unfortunately.

Comment: Updated fiddle: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Kciaab/4

I could not get the `Enter` keypress to work unfortunately. It's that change to the default `Enter` behaviour, adding the <br> element that is what is needed though from the sound of it. So a change from `shift+Enter` is possible, but not sure about changing the `Enter` keydown behaviour to make a <br>.